# Tomcat 7 unable to include templates

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7

I have a web app that includes themes to change the look. I configured tomcat from source on a new server. The project is working locally and on another server. Tomcat does not like the path I am giving it to the /WEB-INF/templates/Demo/base.xhtml template. What could be configured wrong in tomcat to cause this error to happen?

Code:

```
<ui:composition template="#{sessionBean.getSettings().themeFolder}">
```

Code:

```
public String getThemeFolder() {
    return "/WEB-INF/templates/" + themeFolder + "/base.xhtml";
}
```

Error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [/index.xhtml @9,77 <ui:composition template="#{sessionBean.getSettings().themeFolder}"> Invalid path : ] with root cause
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /index.xhtml @9,77 <ui:composition template="#{sessionBean.getSettings().themeFolder}"> Invalid path :
```

Comment: What you have there doesn't look right. Is `themeFolder` a javabean standard property? what does `getSettings()` return?

Comment: getSettings returns a session scoped javabean that has what theme folder is active based on the domain that is accessing the site.